# Triangulation: Find a 3D point minimizing the Distance from N 3D Lines/Rays

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-vision, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

Given Multiple (N) lines in **3D** space, find the **3D** Point minimizing the distance to all lines using Least Squares.

[image]

```
How can I express this in Least Square Matrix Form? Thus, Having:
[A] - Variables matrix ( known )
[x] - Unknown vector
[b] - dependent variables vector

Ax=b => Least-Square
```

Having the distance formula in mind, What should go in A, x, and 'b' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the point minimizing the distance from a set of N lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731066/find-the-point-minimizing-the-distance-from-a-set-of-n-lines)

Comment: I would say ~continuation~, Unfortunately I couldn't add the Image above to the discussion @ the post you describe at a chronological order, and thus, I have created a new post

Comment: Isn't it just the sum of the d squares. For each line you will have a distance, just square these and add.

Comment: Well, I want to have it solved using the LeastSquare Matrix form, for that I have to have:
Matrix [A] for the variables ( known values ), Vector [x] for the Unknowns, Vector [b] for the Dependent variable.
Then this should be solved using the standard Least Square for (Ax=b) ==> x  =  (ATA)-1ATb ( where T - Transpose and -1 is Inverse )

I am trying to figure out how to express the above in matrix form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the formula for `d^2` above you find it is of the form

```
d^2 = Cxx Px Px + Cxy Px Py + ... + Ex Px + Ey Py + Ez Pz + F
```

where Cxx, Ex, F etc are constants depending on A and B vectors.  Now take the sum of these for each line, lets call this sum S which is a quadratic in Px, Py and Pz.

```
S = Sxx Px Px + Sxy Px Py + ... +  Rx Px + Ry Py + Rz Pz + T
```

Now differentiate

```
dS/dx = 2 Sxx Px +   Sxy Py +   Sxz Pz + Rx
dS/dy =   Syx Px + 2 Syy Py +   Syz Pz + Ry
dS/dz =   Szx Px +   Szy Py + 2 Szz Pz + Rz
```

As S is a minimum each of these must be zero. You can write this in matrix form
A x = b. [A] is the matrix of the Sxx etc , b is the vector -[Rx,Ry,Rz] and x is the vector [Px,Py,Pz].

I've now implemented a 2D version as a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/Y3yT9/1/
it suprisingly simple to do the guts of the algorithm is

```
var sxx = 0;
var sxy = 0;
var syy = 0;
var rx = 0;
var ry = 0;
var t = 0;
// each line is defined by a x + b y + c = 0
lines.forEach(function(line, index, array) {
    var div = line.a * line.a + line.b * line.b;
    sxx += line.a * line.a / div;        
    sxy += line.a * line.b / div;        
    syy += line.b * line.b / div;        
    rx += line.a * line.c / div;        
    ry += line.b * line.c / div;        
    t += line.c * line.c / div;        
});
// Derivative of S wrt x and y is
//  2 sxx x + 2 sxy y + 2 rx = 0
//  2 sxy x + 2 syy y + 2 ry = 0

// Solve this pair of linear equations
var det = sxx * syy - sxy * sxy;
if(Math.abs(det) < 1e-6) {
    sol = { x: -10, y: -10 };
    return;
}
// (x) =  1  ( syy    -sxy ) ( -rx )
// ( ) = --- (             ) (     )
// (y)   det ( -sxy    sxx ) ( -ry )
var x = ( - syy * rx + sxy * ry ) / det;
var y = (   sxy * rx - sxx * ry ) / det;
console.log("x "+x+" y "+y);
sol = { x: x, y: y };
return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is very helpful, Having in mind Ax=b, while it is clear to me how to express the vector [x], I am not sure I understand the difference between the 'Sxx' and 'Rx' notation of your response.

Comment: The Sxx and the Rx are just constants. If you expand the formula for d^2 you get a quadratic in Px, Py, Pz there will be 9 quadratic terms, 3 linear terms and a constant. Now add these together, one for each line, this again gives a quadratic, Ive use Sxx, Rx and T for these constants.

Comment: A minimal distance between a point P and a line AB will always be on another line TP which is perpendicular to AB, having that said, there will be needed at-least two lines to triangulate the point minimizing the distance, It is not clear to me how to incorporate the two lines in that aspect, my guess is that the above Ax=b system will result in infinite solutions ( the perpendicular line )...

Comment: Add the terms of the d^2 together. Thats what least squares does, it minimises the sums of squares.

Comment: I must be missing something here, The SUM of squares can either present a single OR multiple lines, for a single line there are infinite solutions ( those points on the line ), having in mind that the coefficients of a SINGLE line can present the SUM of coefficients of a set of different MULTIPLE lines, 
Why should this linear system result a single and not infinite solutions ?

Comment: The lines are all known, call them l1, l2, l3, ... We want to find a single point P. Let d1, d2, d3, ... be the distances from P to the nearest point on each line. Add the square of these together gives you S. With one line the matrix A will drop rank and you will have solutions along the line. The simplest non-degenerate case will be two lines. There is a unique shortest line segment joining the two lines and the least squares will find the mid point of this segment, if you think about it must be the mid point which minimises the sum of the two squared distances.